# Z3 solver: mapping boolean to integer and computing sums

Tags: z3

I have a boolean expression

```
f(x1, x2, x3, ..., xn)
```

Let m(x) be a mapping from {true,false} to {1,0} and let

```
g(x1, x2, x3, ..., xn) = m(x1) + m(x2) + ... + m(xn)
```

g() is computing the number of its arguments that evaluate to true.

I have some constraints on k = g(x1, x2, ..., xn) such as leastsignificantbit(k) = 1.

How can I specify this in Z3?

As a concrete example: Let f1 = a OR b, f2 = c OR d OR e, c = leastsignificantbit(m(a) + m(b)) where m(x) is defined as above.

I am using the Z3 .net API, however, it is not necessary for the answer to use the .net API as long as it uses the Z3 concepts in any supported language binding.

Comment: in your concrete example, how is `f1`, `f2` related to the definition of `c`? Would be best to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've figured it out. I can use an XOR of the clauses to compute leastsignificantbit of the number of true clauses. It will be true if an odd number of clauses is true and will be false with a zero or an even number of clauses being true.